# Java child class not able to implement parent class's abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, parent-child

I have the following. If I keep the @Override, I get an error that the method must implement or override a supertype method. If I remove it, I get an error that the child class must implement the inherited abstract method. Why won't the below code work, and how can I make it do what I intend?

BaseClass.java:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    ...
    protected abstract <T extends Inputs> T doStuff(T inputs);

    public abstract static class Inputs
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

ChildClass.java:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    ...
    @Override
    protected Inputs doStuff(Inputs inputs)
    {
        return inputs;
    }

    public static class Inputs extends BaseClass.Inputs
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass.Inputs>
```

and:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass<ChildClass.Inputs>
```

Which means you need to change `doStuff()` so that it returns T (in `BaseClass`), without having a declared type variable:

```
public abstract T doStuff(T inputs);
```

Comment: This is the correct idea.  Just a nitpick in that it should be `BaseClass<T extends BaseClass.Inputs>` and `extends BaseClass<ChildClass.Inputs>`.

Comment: @rgettman argh, answered too fast and didn't see that `Inputs` was an embedded class -- thanks for fixing!

Comment: Thanks! @rgettman's nitpick is correct. Is there a cleaner way, instead of having Class.Inputs?

Comment: @user1145925 well, do you really need to embed that class to start with?

Comment: Yes. I must have Inputs embedded in both classes.

Comment: If you want to avoid the dot-crazy writing, the only solution I see is that the inner classes have other names, such as for instance `BaseInputs` and `ChildInputs`

Comment: Thanks, I won't do that; I guess I'm ok with the dots.